# Erro na leitura do TXT C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, txt

estou tendo um problema na leitura de um arquivo TXT devido a variações de linhas que ele possui

a ideia é a seguinte (ler o arquivo txt e enviar essas informações para o banco de dados)
porém está ocasionando um erro de leitura que não consigo corrigir!

modelo do txt usado:

```
16456602|618|0|0|0
1645671603|1007|100|500
164571603|1021|1|5000|500|6|0|0
1647103|10021|2|5000|500|6|0|0
1645671605|8|12001
1645605|3|127001|38171
1645671605|6103|245
16671606|8|45220
```

código usado:

```
          string caminhoArquivo = "./arquivo.txt";

            var consulta =
                         from c in
                        (from linha in File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo)

                         let clienteDados = linha.Split('|')
                         select new Cliente()
                         {
                             V1 = clienteDados[0],
                             V2 = clienteDados[1],
                             V3 = clienteDados[2],
                             V4 = clienteDados[3],
                             V5 = clienteDados[4],
                             V6 = clienteDados[5],
                             V7 = clienteDados[6],
                             V8 = clienteDados[7],

                         })
                         where c.V2 == "1007"
                         select c;

            foreach (var item in consulta)
            {
                InsertInfos.V1 = item.V1;
                InsertInfos.V2 = item.V2;
                InsertInfos.V3 = item.V3;
                InsertInfos.V4 = item.V4;
                InsertInfos.V5 = item.V5;
                InsertInfos.V6 = item.V6;
                InsertInfos.V7 = item.V7;
                InsertInfos.V8 = item.V8;

                UserModel UserModel = new UserModel();
                UserModel.InsertValores(InsertInfos.V1, InsertInfos.V2, InsertInfos.V3, InsertInfos.V4, InsertInfos.V5, InsertInfos.V6, InsertInfos.V7, InsertInfos.V8);


            }
```

o problema está quando ele vai retornar o V2 em diante, pois pelo que entendi tem algo a ver com o número de colunas do txt serem variadas!!!

alguém para me ajudar? '-' preciso muito resolver isso '-'

agradeço antecipadamente!!!

Comment: *" tem algo a ver com o número de colunas do txt serem variadas"* se o número de colunas é variada precisa contar para saber quantas colunas tem, por exemplo com `clienteDados.Count`

Comment: mas como eu faria isso? tens algum exemplo? eu tentei o count, tentei o lenght, mas nao consegui aplicar no código de maneira efetiva '-'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez não seja a forma mais otimizada, mas é funcional.
A ideia aqui é concatenar o valor que vem na linha (pode vir nenhum valor como pode vir até 8 valores) e concatenar com uma lista de nulos e depois pegar os 8 primeiros registros começando pelos que vieram do seu arquivo, com isso você evita erros de tamanho de array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

string fileName = @"..\arquivo.txt";


IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(fileName);
string[] nulls = new string[8];

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split('|');
    new Cliente().InsertModels(parts.Concat(nulls).Take(8).ToList());
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));

public class Cliente
{
    public Cliente() { }

    public string V1 { get; set; }
    public string V2 { get; set; }
    public string V3 { get; set; }
    public string V4 { get; set; }
    public string V5 { get; set; }
    public string V6 { get; set; }
    public string V7 { get; set; }
    public string V8 { get; set; }

    public string InsertModels(List<string> fullList)
    {
        V1 = fullList[0];
        V2 = fullList[1];
        V3 = fullList[2];
        V4 = fullList[3];
        V5 = fullList[4];
        V6 = fullList[5];
        V7 = fullList[6];
        V8 = fullList[7];

        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, estou muito grato pela sua ajuda, apenas acrescentei meu código para enviar a informação ao sql e ficou 100% funcional!

agradeço muito, de coração, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda e contribuição!